# How do I NOT autoload a class in php?

Tags: php, autoload, autoloader

the autoloader at the beginning of my php code

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include_once $class_name . '.class.php';
}
```

is causing a call to `new MongoClient();` to fail with the error *`Warning: include_once(MongoClient.class.php): failed to open stream`*

How can I use the autoloader for my classes and still use the standard classes?

Note: MongoDb has been installed with PECL and works fine with the autoloading function removed. mongo-1.3.0beta2 on php 5.4.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__autoload()`, if defined, is called each time you try to access a class that has not been imported manually using `require_once()` or `include_once()` and is not part of the PHP internal classes.

In your case the `__autoload()` is triggered although you try to access a PHP internal class - `MongoClient` that is provided by the php-mongo extension. When you are not using `__autoload()` it works as expected.

It looks like the extension doesn't speak well with the PHP interpreter. You should first try an update from the beta to the stable 1.3.1 version. If this won't help, it will need further investigation.

---

Btw, if you try to instantiate a `MongoClient` object inside a namespace use `\MongoClient()`, like this:

```
namespace Foo;

$client = new \MongoClient();
```

The `\` refers to the global namespace.

Comment: What version of PHP and the Mongo extension do you use?

Comment: I tried it with the version 1.3.1 of mongo and PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 and it works with and without the autoloader. Either its a bug in PHP or mongo or the versions you are using aren't compatible.

Comment: Note, pecl installed mongo 1.3.1 by default. It is marked as stable. You should try an update of mongo.

Comment: Upgrading to the latest mongo 1.3.2RC1 fixed the problem.

Comment: use instead `new \MongoClient()`

Answer (score 4):

PHP will **not** try to autoload anything that is in the stl (like PDO, mysqli, etc)

If `MongoClient` is not one of those types of classes, it will try to autoload it.

[Make sure you have PECL installed](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php)

Comment: This makes sense, and changing MongoClient to Mongo in my code removes the error. But http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongo.php lists Mongo as deprecated and that MongoClient should be used.

Answer (score 0):

As Neal pointed out, make sure you have the PECL mongo client installed and keep in mind that some times PHP uses a different `php.ini` file for the CLI.

If in CLI, you can get the correct `php.ini` by doing:

```
php -r "phpinfo();" | grep "php.ini"
```

So, after checking the PECL, make sure you have the `extension=mongo.so` in the correct `php.ini`