# Temporarily disable autoload stack

Tags: php, autoloader

Can someone please tell me if it is possible to temporarily disable the spl_autoloader and then enable it later, and if so how? Alternatively, if that is not possible, is there a way to 'pull' the autoload stack into a temporary variable, which causes the stack to deactivate (when its empty) and then re-register everything from that variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I NOT autoload a class in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923447/how-do-i-not-autoload-a-class-in-php)

Comment: Did not test it. But I think you can use [spl_autoload_functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-functions.php) to collect the functions and then unregister them with [spl_autoload_unregister](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-unregister.php)

Comment: Thanks that worked! I tested and put in as an answer crediting you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Credit to Bart who had the solution

> you can use spl_autoload_functions to collect the functions and then
>   unregister them with spl_autoload_unregister

and I tested with the following which worked:

```
<?php

$autoloadFuncs = spl_autoload_functions();
var_dump($autoloadFuncs);

foreach($autoloadFuncs as $unregisterFunc)
{
    spl_autoload_unregister($unregisterFunc);
}

// Code goes here that you dont want the auto loader enabled for.

foreach($autoloadFuncs as $registerFunc)
{
    spl_autoload_register($registerFunc);
}
?>
```

Comment: That comment seems out of place as this question makes no mention of mongo. Also I don't see why you found this answer unsuitable for this question asked.

Comment: I have try to use spl_autoload_unregister to unregister but it return false. and I re-check the spl_autoload_functions() it return the same autoload function

Comment: @YuanChen if it returned false then it failed to unregister which explains why it returns the same. Find out why `spl_autoload_unregister($unregisterFunc);` is returning false.

Comment: @Programster how can I find out why spl_autoload_unregister($unregisterFunc); return false. I have look around but still not find the reason my PHP version is 5.2.9.

Comment: @YuanChen I don't know, but I highly recommend testing the same code on php 5.3 or higher. Things like namespace support came in then.

Comment: @Programster Thanks, I have tried with PHP 5.3 and it work ok. look like is is a bug in PHP 5.2